# Sacredness of vedas

Tags: vedas, mantras

What is so sacred (in a spiritual sense) about Vedic mantras? Just to be clear, I haven't read Vedas but I have read some verses from time to time. I think the verses are good and teach us something valuable but I'm not able to see spiritual sacredness in Vedas. Thoughts of spiritual masters like Swami Vivekananda, Ramana maharishi will be appreciated.

What I mean by Sacredness in spiritual sense is that the knowledge contained in Vedas can not be gained from any other place or by understanding it alone you will become enlightened or go to some kind of heaven or gain some other worldly abilities and insights or become like god(which you really are according to Advaita) etc.

Comment: They are sacred because they are directly from God and are eternal.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda is this the only reason...could you tell what were the thoughts swami vivekananda on this too...i've edited the question.

Comment: From the GODS to the men. There is nothing to understand.

Comment: Are you looking for Spiritual hymns from Vedas eg. [Naasadiya Sukta](https://dharmawiki.org/index.php/Nasadiya_Sukta_(%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D))?

Comment: @Pandya no, that one is a spiritual verse....but what about verses which are just prayers to gods, i don't see any big purpose in those verses; in my opinion Vedas are not supposed to contain such types of verses.(i.e. verses which are just prayers)

Comment: If you ask" I have seen so many cows in my life, they don't look sacred to me. So why are cows sacred?" -- how to answer it? Your current question is almost similar.@dark_prince

Comment: Well Swami Vivekananda(or any enlightened person) can answer it @Rickross :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have posted below some of Swami Vivekananda's writings on the Vedas. Only the spiritual message and not every verse of the Vedas is important.

> There was a time when the Vedas themselves were considered eternal in
> the sense in which the divine truths contained therein were changeless
> and permanent and were only revealed to man. At a subsequent time, it
> appears that the utterances of the Vedic hymns with the knowledge of
> its meaning was important; and it was held that the hymns themselves
> must have had a divine origin. **At a still later period, the meaning of
> the hymns showed that many of them could not be of divine origin,
> because they inculcated upon mankind performance of various unholy
> acts, such as torturing animals; and we can find many ridiculous
> stories in the Vedas.** The correct meaning of the statement "The Vedas
> are beginningless and eternal" is that the law or truth revealed by
> them to man is permanent and changeless. Logic, geometry, chemistry,
> etc., reveal also a law or truth which is permanent and changeless and
> in that sense they are also beginningless and eternal. But no truth or
> law is absent from the Vedas, and I ask any one of you to point out to
> me any truth which is not treated of in them. (5)

**(The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Vol.5: With the Swami Vivekananda at Madura, pp.205-206)**

> The Hindus have received their religion through revelation, the Vedas.
> They hold that the Vedas are without beginning and without end. It may
> sound ludicrous to this audience [in the West] how a book can be
> without beginning or end. But by the Vedas no books are meant. They
> mean the accumulated treasury of spiritual laws discovered by
> different persons in different times. Just as the law of gravitation
> existed before its discovery and would exist if all humanity forgot
> it, so is it with the laws that govern the spiritual world. The moral,
> ethical, and spiritual relations between soul and soul and between
> individual spirits and the Father of all spirits were there before
> their discovery, and would remain even if we forget them. (6)

**(The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Vol.1: Paper on Hinduism, pp.6-7.)**

> [Vedic] principles have existed throughout time; and they will exist.
> They are non-created - uncreated by any laws which science teaches us
> today. They remain covered and become discovered, but are existing
> through all eternity in nature. If Newton had not been born the law of
> gravitation would have remained all the same and would have worked all
> the same. It was Newton's genius which formulated it, discovered it,
> brought it into consciousness, made it a conscious thing to the human
> race. So are these religious laws, the grand truths of spirituality.
> They are working all the time. If all the Vedas and Bibles and Korans
> did not exist at all, if seers and prophets had never been born, yet
> these laws would exist. They are only held in abeyance, and slowly but
> surely will work to raise the human race, to raise human nature. But
> they are the prophets who see them, discover them; and such prophets
> are discoverers in the field of spirituality. As Newton and Galileo
> were prophets of physical science, so are they prophets of
> spirituality. They can claim no exclusive right to any one of these
> laws; they are the common property of all nature.
>
> The Vedas, as the Hindus say, are eternal. We now understand what they
> mean by their being eternal, i.e. that the laws have neither beginning
> nor end. Earth after earth, system after system, will evolve, run for
> a certain time, and then dissolve back into chaos; but the universe
> remains the same. Millions and millions of systems are being born,
> while millions are being destroyed. The universe remains the same. The
> beginning and end of time can be told as regards a certain planet;
> but, as regards the universe, time has no meaning at all. So are the
> laws of nature, the physical laws, the mental laws, the spiritual
> laws, without beginning or end; and it is within a few years,
> comparatively speaking - a few thousand years at best - that man has
> tried to reveal them. The infinite mass remains before us. Therefore
> the one great lesson that we learn from the Vedas, at the start, is
> that religion has just begun. The infinite ocean of spiritual truth
> lies before us to be worked on, to be discovered, to be brought into
> our lives. The world has seen thousands of prophets, and the world has
> yet to see millions. (7)

**(The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Vol.6: The Methods and Purpose of Religion, pp.8-9.)**

Comment: The point in bold is what i was looking for. So some vedic hymns can be considered as of non divine origin.

Comment: Yes. Just go through Shankara's commentary on Gita 18.66 where he discusses the issue of Vedic infallibility: 'The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is misconceived. The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not confined to the sphere of direct perceptions,......'